# Mongoose aggregation with $sum returning 0?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know several question have been asked in here but no one give me the correct answer. So basically I have Schema like here

```
    const cashFlowSchema = new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    amount: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: String
});
```

And then I tried to create get `sum` for amount with `aggregate` like this

```
CashFlow.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        balance: { $sum: "$amount" }
    }
}], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

And give the result like this

`[ { _id: null, balance: 0 } ]`

But if I try in Robo3T (previously Robomongo), it give me correct answer. I use mongodb version `3.4`. Thank you before.

**Update**
I found the answer, so it's my silly mistake. After I enable `debug` mode in mongoose, it show I'm make wrong connection to the collection. After fix it, I get the correct result. I will delete this question soon, thank's all before.

Comment: Remove the last `$project` stage. Or use `{ $project: { balance: 1 }}`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet sorry, i edited the code sample above. I have tried with or without `$project` but the result is the same.

Comment: have a look https://mongoplayground.net/p/0m_f9Vdsyjs

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet on the playground the result is correct, but when I implement on my node app the result still 0 :(

Comment: Are you sure you values are number not string

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yes, the values I set to `Number`